# Timing issue while looping over the testing tool command line process

Tags: restart, shutdown, sleep-mode, system-shutdown, hibernation

I developed a automation script in python for the testing tool. I created a command line process to execute the test using the tool in the windows system. I'm iterating with for loop using the command line process and in each iteration new process invoked since we are parsing the iteration value for the command line. Here I'm facing the timing issue between previous (i-1, previous) iterations and (i, current) iteration process. when still the (i-1, previous) iteration is running in the system (i, current) iteration begin it's execution. ( **For example : The testing tool process has to complete reboot in 2.5 minutes but since I increased the delay between each loop now complete reboot takes 4.2 minutes which is not expected if I decrease the delay between each iteration then reboot is not taking place for current iteration since the previous process is still running**) Note: we can't kill the previous running process because still the testing tool collecting the logs.

Can anyone help here to overcome this issue?

I given considerable delay between each iteration but more delay causing increased total execution time which is not expected. ( For example : If I want to loop for the range of 1500 then the execution of testing tool will be around (2.5 minutes * 1500 iterations = 3750 minutes or 62.5 hours or 2.60 days) which is expected but since I given around ( 4.14 minutes * 1500 = 6210 minutes or 103.5 hours or 4.31 days) which is not expected.

I'm expecting each testing tool command line process for each iteration needs to be completed with this calculation (2.5 minutes * 1500 iterations = 3750 minutes or 62.5 hours or 2.60 days) for (Hibernate, sleep, shutdown and warm restart feature in windows platform).